# Secure, automatic tunnelling dæmon on Linux server?

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6, tunneling

I've been looking for software to do this for a little while but seem to find only pages that talk about projects that never materialized, or are not capable of running on a Linux system.

Does anyone know of a tunnel setup dæmon that will run on Linux?  It doesn't have to do a whole heck of a lot; doesn't even have to have a fancy UI.  I can wrap a UI around it for the Web or a different type of interface.

The reason for this is that I am looking to create a setup where the client systems can roam around the Internet, but there is a problem:  IPv6 is not universally available.  I don't have a problem with that; I have tons and tons of IPv6 address space and can support the required number of clients via my Internet connection.  However, what I need is for those client workstations to, when they boot up:

- If an IPv6 connection is present, use it and login/authenticate.
- If an IPv4 connection is present, but an IPv6 connection is **not** present, setup an IPv6-over-IPv4 tunnel using a particular IPv4 endpoint on the Internet.  The IPv4 endpoint that we're talking about here is the server that I want the tunnel dæmon on.

IOW, if there is no IPv6 connection, the client will have to authenticate to the IPv4 tunnel server in order to be able to build a tunnel.  Then an IPv6 network connection will be created and all will be well.

Of course, this is only a temporary measure, but as it so happens, it's needed now, before the majority of the Internet is actually providing IPv6 connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about setting up a [ipv6 tunnel broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_broker).  Perhaps via [6in4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4), [AYIYA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AYIYA), or [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/).  For example, here's a page with an [example of setting up OpenVPN as a tunnel broker](https://www.zagbot.com/openvpn_ipv6_tunnel.html).

So then you'd just need to have a script on the client end that would route over the tunnel only when there wasn't a local IPv6 route, perhaps via an OpenVPN "up script"?

Comment: It looks like AYIYA is most likely what I am after.  Seems there is a single implementation, AICCU, that is both cross platform and freely licensed—both properties that I would need.  I need to do a bit more digging to see if it will also run as a Windows service, and will likely have to make a local version for my own administrative domains, but that is an excellent pointer.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're describing [teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling), or it's Open Source version [miredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miredo)